# java.lang.illegalStateException during performing Search using Android Search Configration

Tags: android, search, illegalstateexception

I am trying to implement search in my android app. I have followed the step as suggested by the tutorials to make search possible. I have implemented search with a button.As soon as I press the button,not always but sometimes my Logcat show this error and application stops.This doesnot happen always but sometimes,I dont know why this happening as if this is an issue than the error should showup always when I click the search button.

```
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3050)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3045)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    ... 11 more
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:543)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:518)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:580)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:637)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.SearchDialog.updateSearchAppIcon(SearchDialog.java:438)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.SearchDialog.updateUI(SearchDialog.java:391)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.SearchDialog.show(SearchDialog.java:278)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.SearchDialog.doShow(SearchDialog.java:230)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.SearchDialog.show(SearchDialog.java:212)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.SearchManager.startSearch(SearchManager.java:526)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at  android.app.SearchManager.startSearch(SearchManager.java:503)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.Activity.startSearch(Activity.java:3055)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at android.app.Activity.onSearchRequested(Activity.java:3018)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    at com.vahzay.android.smstrove.ListMessages.onsearchClick(ListMessages.java:150)
01-07 13:32:54.759: E/AndroidRuntime(11826):    ... 14 more
```

Here is the snippet that cause this error

```
    public void onsearchClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.searcher) {
        Log.i("search has been clicked", "show");

        // this method is used to call the search activity from the
        // listmessages activity no intent is used as its need a special
        // functionality
        onSearchRequested(); // line no 150
    }

}
```

Comment: the real issue is `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` you have too many bitmaps in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash happened due to `Out of Memory Exception` as given in your log. The search icon is not being loaded properly. For using Bitmaps efficiently take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: can you please elaborate the difference between drawables and bitmap coz I am using drawables in my app and confuse about bitmaps..